# How do I disable the "You need to format drive Z" popup on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, rufus

I'm trying to use Rufus to create a bootable Windows 10 USB but every time it deletes the partitions Windows will popup with the `You need to format drive Z:`.

This causes Rufus to fail as another application (Windows explorer) has control of the device mid way through the install.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, because you're doing it from Windows, why aren't you using the official media creator tool?

Comment: Because Windows 10 can be used without activation. As can Windows 7. You need to activate to use the media creation tool.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that but then all my Windows installations are activated (because they're all legal OEM or retail licenses) . We won't help you pirating Windows and that includes attempts to use an OEM license in any machine that isn't the one that came with said license (OEM licenses live and die in the machine they were bought with).

Comment: Yeah most definitely not interested in pirating. Thankfully Windows allow you to continue using 7 with nagging activation popups. Windows 10 seems to just disallow editing settings from the metro type UI and has an "activate windows" watermark on the desktop.